# How to clip polygon by line feature QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip, masking

The clip tool will only allow for clipping by another polygon, I would like to clip polygon features by a line feature. Had tried installing the digitizing feature however the cut by lines button is no longer there.

Comment: Try `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Split with lines`

Comment: Do you want to use [a tool in processing toolbox](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/_images/toolbox3.png) or [a button tool on a toolbar(in edit mode)](https://issues.qgis.org/attachments/download/6786/add_feature_button.PNG)?